# Jquery - Run code when a person types so many characters?

Tags: jquery

I have a form field that a person enters a telephone number. When they are done adding the telephone number, limited to 10 characters, I want to fire off some jquery code. Is this possible? If so how would I go about doing this?

Comment: There's `keypress` and `keyup`. You probably want `keyup`, although not sure you *really* want `blur`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the user's entering the tenth character:

```
$('input[name="phone"]').keyup(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    if (t.val().length > 9) {
       // do something
    }
});
```

or based on the user leaving the field after entering something:

```
$('input[name="phone"]').change(function() {
    var t = $(this);
    if (t.val().length > 0) {
       // do something
    }
});
```

Comment: A copy-paste (common for filling in information) doesn't trigger keyup, so use a combination of StriplingWarrior's suggestions; in the change event you could also (or instead) check for length of 10 instead of just >0.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#your-input").live("keyup", function() {
    if ($(this).val().length === 10){
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#id input").mask("9999999999");
```

http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/

```
$('#id').keypress(function(e) {

 if (  $('#id input').val().length >= 10 ) { 
      alert('Helo World');
  }
});
```

use